# If I use gussets and hurricane ties can I skip the collar and rafter ties for a 16x24 shed build?

Tags: roof, shed

I want to have high ceilings for storage so I'd prefer to have no rafter ties and I figured if I have the gussets I can skip the collar ties too. The ties are cheap enough to install which I think should replace the benefit of rafter ties but will a plywood gusset work to replace the collar tie? I'm in MA so we do get a snow load.

Width is 16', length is 24'.
The roof here is 4' high, so 8/4' rise.
Rafters will be 2x6

[image]

Comment: The drawing is helpful. It would be even more helpful if there were some dimensions added (at least in the text).

Comment: I would not rely on just the gussets to hold those rafters in place.  There's an awful lot of tension in those gussets under a MA snow load.  What does you local inspection department say?

Comment: Also, the only way I would consider what you proposing is to have the rafters bear upon a ridge beam at the peak of the roof.

Comment: And where would the collar ties go if they were not eliminated?  Would they be 1/3 of the way down from the peak, or would they rest on the walls, thus becoming rafter ties.

Comment: Like SteveSh says, you're going to need a ridge beam to carry the load of the roof without bowing out the walls.  As for the collar ties, maybe you can look to see if there's a strong tie for this application.  Where I am, I'd need to get an engineer to sign off on any design in order to get a permit, so I might as well consult with one on this question.  BTW, don't forget that hip roofs exist.

Comment: You might want to look at what did for a similarly sized deck, in this post - https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/201716/building-a-deck-without-help/201746#201746

Comment: How would having a ridge beam make up for no collar ties or rafter "ties"?  Are there going to be joists across the top plates?

Comment: Having a true ridge beam changes the loads.  The static loads (the roof itself, snow, etc) now bear straight down vertically to whatever is supporting the ridge beam and the lower ends of the roof rafters.  With this configuration, there is no spreading force to try and force the walls apart.  Go look at the picture of my deck from the post I referenced above,

Comment: I went this route because of cost and I can do it solo. If I did the ridge beam I would have to find a large beam that spans the 24' length which would be pricey and hard to install alone. With this design could I just add rafter ties and not colar ties even though at that point I'm not sure if matters as the attic space is hard to get to because of the rafters.

Comment: Could I not put ceiling joists/rafter ties near the end of the wall and just have them in the middle? If the rafters are 24" spaced if I were to not include the first two but include all the rest would that work fine? That would give me access to the space above while keeping the rafter ties in place.

Comment: Something like this: [Rafters ties removed](https://img.proto.tools/uploads/faHMSZbkf-rafter.jpg)

Comment: So then why not just frame the opening in like you would for a stairway?  Double up the rafters on either side of the opening and connect them together with doubled up short headers/trimmer (not sure if I have the terminology right).  Google "Framing a stairway" to see what I mean.  Can't put pictures in a comment, unfortunately.